# ModelState is coming false even when I've modified the property in action filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I've modified the ActionType in the following action filter itself but still getting model state error as "The field ActionType must match the regular expression '1|2|3|4'."

For my model property as

```
[RegularExpression("1|2|3|4")]

public int ActionType { get; set; }
```

My ActionType Enum is

```
 public enum ActionType
        {
            Add = 1,
            Update = 2,
            Delete = 3,
            Search = 4
        }
```

Action filter is

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var formData = actionContext.ActionArguments.FirstOrDefault().Value as EntityBase;
            if (formData != null)
            {
                string methodType = actionContext.Request.Method.Method;
                switch (methodType.ToUpper())
                {
                    case "POST":
                        formData.ActionType = (int)ActionType.Add;
                        break;
                    case "PUT":
                        formData.ActionType = (int)ActionType.Update;
                        break;
                    case "DELETE":
                        formData.ActionType = (int)ActionType.Delete;
                        break;
                    case "GET":
                        formData.ActionType = (int)ActionType.Search;
                        break;
                    // Your errors
                }
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
```

Comment: Model binding and validation occurs **before** action filters are fired

Comment: Hi @Stephen Would you please suggest where shall I do this?

Comment: You could create a custom model binder to prevent the validation error being added or (probably easier but I've not tested it) access the `actionContext.ModelState` property and clear the error - `if (actionContext.ModelState.ContainsKey("ActionType")) { actionContext.ModelState["ActionType"].Errors.Clear(); }` But why put a validation attribute on the property if your always going to set it in the action filter anyway?

Comment: Ohk That's right that I am always going to use it, but In some cases I may ask client to add this as request parameter, Anyways Thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the data annotation on ActionType property to use Range instead of RegularExpression??

```
[Range(1, 4)]
public int ActionType { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi @Krishna Teja, This doesn't resolve my problem, I've taken your suggestion and will make the change